Stylus doesn't work in specific apps but works under some x11 and wayland apps
My Laptop has a wacom tablet and pen integrated in the internal screen (Lenovo Yoga 7 14AHP9 & Lenovo Digital Pen 2 (i already added Wacom 5360 to libwacom for gnome settings to recognise it)). For reference, I am using nixos (24.11-beta) and the gnome desktop environment with wayland. It gets recognised by the kernel driver and inputs are forwarded through libinput and mutter/wayland and xwayland fine. Most applications just work (among those GIMP, libreoffice, all gnome apps including the general DE and even ableton live under wine). libreoffice works on both backends if switching via the GDK_BACKEND variable. Some apps (so far i found Chrome, Obsidian, steam) do not recognise pen input at all though and the pen pointer you get when hovering over the display disappears when moving over such a window. Does anyone know how I can proceed to get pen input working like a mouse (like it works in other applications)?

I have a workaround for Obsidian and potentially other apps, since I have the same issue: if you're using the Flatpak version, you can disable Wayland (Wayland Windowing System, Inherit Wayland Socket) in Flatseal, which gets pen support working for the most part.
The only issue with the above is that some drag and drop stuff no longer works, and if the display scale isn't set to 100% the pen cursor is kinda off in things like Excalidraw (but still draws correctly)
If you install some of the other applications as flatpaks too, doing the same to those might work as well.
